# Images in a JComboBox in a JTable show only path names once selected

Tags: java, image, swing, combobox, jtable

I would like to have a ComboBox with images in a jTable. However, while I can see the images in the drop down menu, I see only their path names as a string in the table once selected. Could anyone point me into the right direction please?

```
/* Modified from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TableRenderDemo */

/*
 * Copyright (c) 2006 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *
 * -Redistribution of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
 *  list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * -Redistribution in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
 *  this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
 *  and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * Neither the name of Sun Microsystems, Inc. or the names of contributors may
 * be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without
 * specific prior written permission.
 *
 * This software is provided "AS IS," without a warranty of any kind. ALL
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED CONDITIONS, REPRESENTATIONS AND WARRANTIES, INCLUDING
 * ANY IMPLIED WARRANTY OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
 * OR NON-INFRINGEMENT, ARE HEREBY EXCLUDED. SUN MIDROSYSTEMS, INC. ("SUN")
 * AND ITS LICENSORS SHALL NOT BE LIABLE FOR ANY DAMAGES SUFFERED BY LICENSEE
 * AS A RESULT OF USING, MODIFYING OR DISTRIBUTING THIS SOFTWARE OR ITS
 * DERIVATIVES. IN NO EVENT WILL SUN OR ITS LICENSORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY LOST
 * REVENUE, PROFIT OR DATA, OR FOR DIRECT, INDIRECT, SPECIAL, CONSEQUENTIAL,
 * INCIDENTAL OR PUNITIVE DAMAGES, HOWEVER CAUSED AND REGARDLESS OF THE THEORY
 * OF LIABILITY, ARISING OUT OF THE USE OF OR INABILITY TO USE THIS SOFTWARE,
 * EVEN IF SUN HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGES.
 *
 * You acknowledge that this software is not designed, licensed or intended
 * for use in the design, construction, operation or maintenance of any
 * nuclear facility.
 */

package tablerenderdemo;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class TableRenderDemo extends JPanel {
    public TableRenderDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        setUpSportColumn(table, table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1));
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    public void setUpSportColumn(JTable table, TableColumn symbolColumn) {
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addItem( new ImageIcon("symbols/circle.png") );
        comboBox.addItem( new ImageIcon("symbols/diamond.png") );
        symbolColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
        symbolColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = {"Last Name","Symbol","# of Years","Vegetarian"};
        private Object[][] data = {
        {"Smith",
         new ImageIcon("symbols/circle.png"), new Integer(5), new     Boolean(false)},
        {"Doe",
         new ImageIcon("symbols/circle.png"), new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)}
        };

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            if (col < 1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRenderDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        TableRenderDemo newContentPane = new TableRenderDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have replaced the table's [default renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), which knows how to render an `Icon`, with an instance of [`DefaultTableCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html), which does not. The latter is a `JLabel` that simply calls `setText()` using the icon's `toString()` method. Remove these lines to see the effect.

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
symbolColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
```